# Turn MoreObjects.toStringHelper(this)...toString() into list of strings

Tags: java, regex

I have a class that implemented the toString() method as something like this:

```
// Returns "ClassName{x=1, y=foo}"
public String toString()
    MoreObjects.toStringHelper(this)
        .add("x", 1)
        .add("y", "foo")
        .add("z", "bar")
        .toString();
}
```

Now in another class I would like to convert the `toString()` result as a String list, like this:

```
["1", "foo", "bar"]
```

Is there a way to use Regex expression to do this?

Comment: Sorry, what is the input?

Comment: Regex can easily find all substring like `ClassName{x=(digit), y=(string)}`. But things can get more complicated if `y=string` part can also hold things like `ClassName{x=(digit), y=(string)}` or some characters like `}` which shouldn't be treated as end of `ClassName{`. So to give you precise answer we would need to know more about your text.

Comment: **Never rely on the output of the toString() method**. IMHO the only real option would be to use the getters to create the right string... And remember: if you solve a problem using regex, you instantly have two problems.

Comment: @Pshemo why promote a bad practice? OP's way of solving a problem is like playing russian roulette, and you are handing him the automatic gun...

Comment: I didn't hand OP gun yet. I want to encourage him to provide more details so we could explain better why this approach may not be good one. I also gave few reasons which shows why this solution could cause some pain.

Comment: thanks for the input. My class consists of 10+ number of fields that are POJOs. The reason why I thought taking adv of the toString method would be nice is that if I happen to add a new field later I only have to update one method. The fields are either Longs or simple alphanumeric strings. So in your opinion, it makes more sense to create the list byhand by calling all the getter functions?

Comment: I'd recommend reading *Effective Java 2nd Ed* Item 10 "Always override `toString()`, which explicitly recommends providing programmatic access to all data in the `toString()` output, in order that you're never tempted to try to parse it out of the string.

Comment: @ppeterka There's no reason not to rely on `toString()` if it's explicitly documented to produce a particular result. And some classes *require* you to use `toString()`, as in the case of `StringBuilder`.

Comment: @shmosel: I admit to have strong views on this 1. `toString()` should **never** be used for serializing an object (what OP is trying to do). IMHO, that is not good OOP practice to have the serialization in the object itself. *What if one needs another, different format on a nice day?* 2. to serialize  an object, there is a vast array of tools available. I don't think there is no *better* way than to invent another one (of course I've been there, done that, got bitten badly).

Comment: @ppeterka I didn't say anything about serialization. Just that it's safe to rely on a method that's properly specified.

Comment: @shmosel Sorry if I sound offensive, no such intention at all, but as the OP does indeed want to serialize an object using a regex'd toString() call, your comment can be misunderstood as an encouragement to go on that slippery road.

Comment: @ppeterka No offense taken. I was just replying to your bolded text. Perhaps I should have been clearer.